# Idris not properly installing/finding packages

Tags: import, module, package, cabal, idris

I'm currently trying to use Blodwen, the prototype of Idris 2, as a backend for a language I'm writing. So I'm trying to import its `ttimp` package for my project.

I go into the Blodwen directory and do `idris --install ttimp.ipkg`

Then in my project's .ipkg I have:

```
opts = "--cg-opt -O2 -i ~/GitHub/Blodwen/"

pkgs = ttimp
```

However, when I run `idris --build myproject.ipkg` I get the error

```
Entering directory `./src'
The following packages were specified but cannot be found:
- ttimp
```

If I remove `ttimp` from `pkgs`, then I get `Can't find import Core/Binary`
 i.e. it can't find the modules from the package.

If I try to build `ttimp` with `TARGET=~/.idris-libs`

```
 idris --install ttimp.ipkg 
Entering directory `./src'
 Can't find import Builtins
 Can't find import Prelude
 Can't find import Data/List
```

**My Question**: How can I make sure `ttimp` is being installed properly? Where does Idris install packages by default? Why isn't Idris finding the library after I've installed it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your current goal is, but when you install blodwen it is using idris to a) install ttimp and to compile blodwen, which is available as the executable `blodwen` afterwards. So if you want to work with blodwen, you should also use blodwen to compile your files and install additional libraries.

Comment: I'm trying to use Blodwen *as a library*. I can build it just fine, but I want to be able to import it from an Idris1 project and call the compiler programmatically, instead of generating text files and passing them on the command line.